# How to generate and auto increment Id with EF Core Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, code-first, dotconnect, ef-core-2.0

I use entity framework core 2 Code first to generate data in Oracle 11g, the entity provider is dotConnect, my POCO class is as follow:

```
public partial class Favoritepage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Personnelid { get; set; }
    public int Pageid { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext is as follow:

```
public partial class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Favoritepage> Favoritepage { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("S_FAVORITEPAGE", "SECURITY")
            .StartsAt(1)
            .IncrementsBy(20);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Favoritepage>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("FAVORITEPAGE", "SECURITY");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
                .HasName("PK_FAVORITEPAGE")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID").ForOracleHasDefaultValueSql("S_FAVORITEPAGE.NEXTVAL");
        });
    }
}
```

When I insert entity like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var dbContxt = new ModelContext())
        {
            var favo = new Favoritepage()
            {
                Pageid = 11253,
                Personnelid = 14313,

            };
            dbContxt.Favoritepage.Add(favo);
            dbContxt.SaveChanges();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

It does not work, and raise expcetion like this `ORA-01400 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'`

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you need all those explicit values in your DBContext? It seems redundant with your entity definition and as I remember correctly a lot of that is done automatically.

Comment: I know this, i just don't know where the problem is, so I add all these definitions

Comment: Take a look at the corresponding database table if the `S_FAVORITEPAGE.NEXTVAL` is set as `DEFAULT` for the `ID` column.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Setting `S_FAVORITEPAGE.NEXTVAL` as `DEFAULT` for the `ID` column is unable,maybe my approach is wrong

Answer (score 3):

this way it worked for me.

```js
builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID")
               .ForOracleUseSequenceHiLo("SEQUENCE_NAME");
```

Comment: Will this create a trigger?

Comment: Starting with `EF core 5` oracle has removed this and expects users to use the `.UseHiLo` method instead

Answer (score 1):

Because Oracle 11g doesn't support column default value from sequence or function, so the only way is using triggers.

```sql
Create Sequence S_XXX;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_XXX
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON XXX
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.ID <= 0) THEN
        SELECT S_XXX.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END T_XXX;
```