# Extending DbSet Add in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, oracle-manageddataaccess

Using EfCore 2.2.4 I am attempted to override the base `DbSet` implementation in one of my Db Contexts.

I am using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` 2.18.6 and if I try to call `context.Customer.Add(new Customer());` (All fields in customer are nullable for arguments sake except the primary key `RECORDNO`) I get the error:

*cannot insert NULL into (SCHEMA.CUSTOMER.RECORDNO)*.

I realise I need to work out and add the `RECORDNO` sequence value to the entity before I commit changes via EfCore and wanted to do this by extending `DbSet.Add` as follows:

```
public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public class OracleDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            SetEntityRecordNumber(entity); //this will use reflection for [Key] attribute and set it to a sequence value I collect from the database
            return base.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public OracleDbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
...
```

However when I now call `context.Customer.Add(new Customer());` the value is null for `context.Customer`.

How do I properly get the `DbContext` to register instances of `OracleDbContext` aswell as `DbContext`, or is there a simpler and still generic way of achieving an override or extension to `DbContext.Add()`?

Comment: There's no reason to extend `Add`. What you ask is specific to each individual *entity*. The obvious fix is to add the key in the application code. A better option would be to mark the primary key properties as database-generated with the [DatabaseGenerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute.databasegeneratedoption?view=netframework-4.8) with an option of Identity, and set the sequence value as a default or an INSERT trigger in the database

Comment: @IvanStoev only if the provider implements them though. Oracle's ADO.NET/EF providers are known for their size and overhead, not their feature completeness.

Comment: [EF Core already supports sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences) as long as the provider implements them.  [This probably duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072734/how-to-generate-and-auto-increment-id-with-ef-core-oracle) shows that at least dotConnect implements them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is indeed individual to each entity, I see your point, however I didn't want to modify the database if I can avoid it hence not using a trigger in the DB.

@IvanStoev I don't have access to the `.HasSequence` extension as I don't think the Oracle EF provider I am using it has implemented it. 

Outside of the actual points made here and my given reason for wanting to do it how would you extend DbSet if you wanted to for any other reason?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *"Oracle's ADO.NET/EF providers are known for their size and overhead, not their feature completeness."* Indeed (unfortunately).

Comment: @BenMaxfield I'm not sure `DbSet` is intended to be extended (although apparently it allows that). But note that most of the `DbSet` methods (except `IQueryable` related) are actually implemented by the `DbContext`, so you might consider overriding `Add` methods there. Or implementing custom `ValueGenerator`.